# How to get text and value from span with div class value in beautiful soup python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an element that is returned in the [33] position with my code below.

```
<span>Beli 4 :<div class="d-inline" currency-format="IDR" value="2500"></div>/ pcs</span>
```

from
https://alfagift.id/p/aice-mochi-ice-cream-klepon-45-ml-772306

I am trying to return Beli 4 : Rp 2.500 / pcs

However I have trouble doing so.

The code I have currently returns all span.

```
item = soup.select('span', {"currency-format":"USD"})
```

How do I get the span text and value in div class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the text by calling `.text` but you should be aware, that you use `select_one()` instead of `select`, cause it could not be called on a `ResultSet` and :

```
item = soup.select_one('span').text
```

There is also another issue, you seem to look for elements with USD, but there is only a IDS value, so more precise selection would be:

```
item = soup.select_one('span:has([currency-format="IDR"])').text
```

---

Just in case, if you have to work with multiple elements / `ResultSet` you have to itrate it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<span>Beli 4 :<div class="d-inline" currency-format="IDR" value="2500">Rp 2.500</div>/ pcs</span>
<span>Beli 5 :<div class="d-inline" currency-format="IDR" value="2500">Rp 2.500</div>/ pcs</span>
<span>Beli 6 :<div class="d-inline" currency-format="IDR" value="2500">Rp 2.500</div>/ pcs</span>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for e in soup.select('span:has([currency-format="IDR"])'):
    print(e.text)
```

Output:

```
Beli 4 :Rp 2.500/ pcs
Beli 5 :Rp 2.500/ pcs
Beli 6 :Rp 2.500/ pcs
```

Comment: hi yeah, thank you for the reminder on USD, when I tried doing the above it doesn't return the values. it returns none

Comment: Answer is based on your example tag, so you might adapt it - could take another look later in time.

Comment: thank you that would be great. I used USD so that it returns all span with select and it;s in the [33] item, because when I tried using IDR the following item doesn't return back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
response = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
response.select_one("span[currency-format*=IDR]").text
```